# GetContextAsync() with Cancellation Support

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm spinning up a `HttpListener` to wait for an `OAuth2` response. In an ideal world, this is only going to be alive for a few seconds while the user logs in in the browser and we get posted the token.

I'd also like for this to have a `CancellationToken` so that the user can stop listening after a delay should they so wish.

My initial idea was to use something along the lines of:

```
_listener.Start();
Task<HttpListenerContext> t = _listener.GetContextAsync();            
while (!cancelled.IsCancellationRequested)
{
     if (t.IsCompleted)
     {
          break;
     }
     await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(100));
}
HttpListenerContext ctx = t.Result;
//...
_listener.Stop();
```

But that doesn't sit right with me for so many reasons (weird `async` usage, polling, etc.).

So then I thought I might be able to use the synchronous version `_listener.GetContext()` in conjunction with `Task.Run(func<T>, CancellationToken)`:

```
_listener.Start()
HttpListenerContext ctx = await Task.Run(() => _listener.GetContext(), cancelled);
//...
_listener.Stop();
```

This is a little better, the code's at least tidier, although it seems hacky using a synchronous version of the method asynchronously with a `Task`...

However this doesn't behave how I'd expect (aborting the running task when the token is cancelled).

This strikes me as something that really ought to be fairly simple to do so I assume I'm missing something.

So my question is thus... How do I listen asynchronously with a `HttpListener` in a cancellable fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In net Core / Net 6 you can set a cancellationToken and/or a timeout through the WaitAsync() method.

```
await http.GetContextAsync().WaitAsync(cancelToken.Token);
await http.GetContextAsync().WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
await http.GetContextAsync().WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),cancelToken.Token);
```

It will throw an exception when cancelled and/or when timed out.

Example:

```
var http = new HttpListener();
http.Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/");
http.Start();
CancellationTokenSource cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
try {                
    var context = await http.GetContextAsync().WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) , cancelToken.Token);
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    Log("Timed out!");
} catch (TaskCanceledException ex) {
    Log("Cancelled!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating cancelable infinite task (`Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, token)` for example) and use `Task.WhenAny`. Something like that:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); // token source controled by consumer "outside"

var token = cts.Token;    
var httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Start();
var t = httpListener.GetContextAsync();
// to cancel the infinite delay task if listener finishes first
var localCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);
var completed = await Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, localCts.Token));
if (completed == t) // check that completed task is one from listener
{
    localCts.Cancel(); // cancel the infinite task
    HttpListenerContext ctx = t.Result;
    //...
}
httpListener.Stop();
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the `GetContextAsync` method does not support cancellation, it basically means that it is unlikely you can cancel the actual IO operation, yet unlikely to cancel the `Task` returned by the method, until you `Abort` or `Stop` the `HttpListener`. So the main focus here is always a *hack* that returns the control flow to your code.

While both the answers from @guru-stron and @peter-csala should do the trick, I just wanted to share another way without having to use `Task.WhenAny`.

You could wrap the task with a `TaskCompletionSource` like this:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> AsCancellable<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (!token.CanBeCanceled)
        {
            return task;
        }

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        // This cancels the returned task:
        // 1. If the token has been canceled, it cancels the TCS straightaway
        // 2. Otherwise, it attempts to cancel the TCS whenever
        //    the token indicates cancelled
        token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled(token), 
            useSynchronizationContext: false);

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                // Complete the TCS per task status
                // If the TCS has been cancelled, this continuation does nothing
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                }
                else if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception);
                }
                else
                {
                    tcs.TrySetResult(t.Result);
                }
            },
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

And flow the control like this:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(3000);

try
{
    var context = await listener.GetContextAsync().AsCancellable(cts.Token);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm making this my accepted answer because it's the best explained, feels the least hacky and has a nice generic implementation. Thanks, and good work!

Comment: Nice stuff! Though I would suggest changing the name of method. AFAIK default convention is that `As` methods are those which give another representation of the same object, this does not. At least `To` or maybe `WrapInCancellable` cause otherwise it is a little bit leaky abstraction - cause the original task, as you mentioned still is not canceled.

Comment: Related: [Why does this cancellable Task result in a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75548399/why-does-this-cancellable-task-result-in-a-memory-leak)

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another solution:

```
var cancellationSignal = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
var contextTask = _listener.GetContextAsync();
using (cancelled.Register(state => ((TaskCompletionSource<object>)state).TrySetResult(null), cancellationSignal))
{
    if (contextTask != await Task.WhenAny(contextTask, cancellationSignal.Task).ConfigureAwait(false))
        break; //task is cancelled
}
```

Because we can't await the `CancellationToken` that's why have to apply the following trick

- The `CancellationToken` does expose a [`Register`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_CancellationToken_Register_System_Action_System_Object__System_Object_) method, where we can define a callback which will be called whenever the cancellation occurs
- Here we can provide a delegate which sets an awaitable to completed
- So, we can `await` that task

In order to create a `Task` which is set to completed whenever the cancellation occurs I've used [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=net-5.0). You could also use [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync?view=net-5.0) or any other signalling object which has async wait, like [`AsyncManualResetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asyncmanualresetevent?view=visualstudiosdk-2019).

- So, we pass the `cancellationSignal` to the `Register` as a `state` parameter

  - Inside the delegate we have to cast it back to TCS to be able to call the `TrySetResult` on it
- Inside the using block we await a `Task.WhenAny`

  - It will return that `Task` which finishes first
  - If that `Task` is the cancellation then we can `break` / `return` / `throw` ...
  - If that `Task` is the `contextTask` then we can continue the normal flow