# Why does this cancellable Task result in a memory leak?

Tags: c#, async-await, memory-leaks, cancellation-token

I have a program where part of it reads from the console for input from another program.

So I have a `Task` that looks like this:

```
public async Task ConsoleHandler()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            string command = (await Console.In.ReadLineAsync().AsCancellable(
                _cancellationTokenSource.Token))!;

            //Process the command
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Do something to report then wait for next command
        }
    }
}
```

Normally `Console.ReadLineAsync` is not a cancel-able task, so I used the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69715297/getcontextasync-with-cancellation-support/69861689#69861689) to create the following task extension:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> AsCancellable<T>(this Task<T> task,
        CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (!token.CanBeCanceled)
        {
            return task;
        }

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        // This cancels the returned task:
        // 1. If the token has been canceled, it cancels the TCS straightaway
        // 2. Otherwise, it attempts to cancel the TCS whenever
        //    the token indicates cancelled
        token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled(token),
            useSynchronizationContext: false);

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            // Complete the TCS per task status
            // If the TCS has been cancelled, this continuation does nothing
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            }
            else if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception!);
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(t.Result);
            }
        },
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

The problem, when running this in .NET Core 6.0.10, is that memory grows until I run out of memory (this is running on an embedded Linux device). Removing the call to `.AsCancellable(...)` removes the memory leak. This happens even if there is no input on the Console.

Why does this task extension cause a memory leak?

Comment: what's being retained? try using a profiler

Comment: @DanielA.White There's a recursion in the reference to `AsCancellable`, but I don't really understand how that is happening, nothing above is apparently calling itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AsCancellable` is not implemented correctly. It [registers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register) a callback on the `token`, and never disposes the registration. So the registrations are piling up in the internal structures of the `CancellationToken`.

Since you are using .NET 6, you have no need for the `AsCancellable` method. You can use the [`WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync) API instead, which is, of course, correctly implemented.